# Is there some way to improve the render quality of flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

[image]

Take a look. On the right side: Chrome rendering a cover album of AC/DC. On the left side: It's the very same file, same dimensions, but rendered by Flutter.

In fact all the images of my Flutter Web project is actually in poor quality on the productions build. Is there some how to improve it ?

Comment: which one you are using, html or canvas renderer?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh , I've no clue...I just followed the documentation... I just created the project and then: Flutter Build Web.